# Green's function for Dirichlet problem on a half disk

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $D=\{z=(x,y):x^2+y^2<R^2, y>0\}$ be the half disk with radius R. Then if we consider the Dirichlet problem on this domain, i.e., we want to find 
$$
\Delta u=0, ~~z\in D,\\
u=f,~~z\in\partial D,
$$
where $f$ is continuous.Then what's the expression of solution $u(z)$ in terms of it's boundary value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
u(z) &= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int\limits_{|\zeta| = 1 \atop \operatorname{Im} z > 0} f(\zeta) \Big( \frac{\zeta}{\zeta-z} +  \frac{\bar\zeta}{\overline{\zeta-z}} - \frac{\zeta}{\zeta-\bar z} - \frac{\bar \zeta}{\bar\zeta-z} \Big)\,\frac{d\zeta}{\zeta} \\
&\qquad + \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{-1}^1 f(t) \Big( \frac{z-\bar z}{|t-z|^2} - \frac{z-\bar z}{|1-tz|^2} \Big)\,dt
\end{align}

See [this paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.facm/1246454030) by Begehr and Vaitekhovich for details. (Assuming $R=1$. General case by scaling.)

Comment: Hi mrf, thanks for the answer!!!
In the paper, the above representation formula seems require the boundary function  f  vanish at the two points x=1, and x = -1. Do you know how to solve the above equation with just continuous function f?